# Connect two seperate PHP forms on the same page due to Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

If I place the Stripe code into the PHP code running above the HTML, the post works but the Stripe does not work. Therefore, I tried running the Stripe code under the HTML code and it works there. However, the $_POST inputs are not being received by the bottom portion. Is there some way I can make the Stripe work in the top portion of the form respond in the second portion?If possible, is there a way to send data from the top PHP code to the bottom PHP code?

The following is the top PHP code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['money1'])){
     $_SESSION['amount'] = 600;
 }
```

The following is the HTML code:

```
   <form action="shop.php" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" style="margin-top:10px;width:175px" class="btn btn-
   success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".moneyOne" value="$6.00" 
   name="money1">
```

The code above opens a modal that leads to the code below.

```
  <script
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  data-amount="600"
  data-name="Example"
  data-description="Widget"
  data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
  data-locale="auto">
  </script>
  </form>
```

This is the bottom PHP Code:

```
   <?php
    $amount =  $_SESSION['amount'];
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      "amount" => $amount,
      "currency" => "usd",
      "description" => "Buy",
      "source" => $token,
      ));

    ?>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `session_start()`?